Trouble Accessing Data from Apache Airflow to External Dashboard App via Docker Volumes
I'm working on a project where I use Apache Airflow to extract and process data, which I then display in a dashboard application. I'm encountering an issue with transferring data from Airflow to my dashboard app.
In my Docker Compose configuration below, I've mapped the raw_files and clean_data folders to /app/raw_files and /app/clean_data respectively, both in Airflow and my dashboard app:
However, upon inspecting the airflow-worker container, I notice it lacks an /app folder; instead, it contains only airflow-worker.pid, airflow.cfg, dags, logs, plugins, and webserver_config.py. As a result, the data extracted and processed seems to be isolated within the airflow-worker container.
How can I ensure that the data from raw_files and clean_data directories can be effectively shared and accessed between Apache Airflow services and my dashboard app?
version: "3"
x-airflow-common: &airflow-common
  image: ${AIRFLOW_IMAGE_NAME:-apache/airflow:2.8.1}
  environment: &airflow-common-env
    AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR: CeleryExecutor
    AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: xx
    AIRFLOW__CELERY__RESULT_BACKEND: db+postgresql://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    AIRFLOW__CELERY__BROKER_URL: redis://:@redis:6379/0
    AIRFLOW__CORE__FERNET_KEY: ""
    AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_ARE_PAUSED_AT_CREATION: "true"
    AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES: "true"
    AIRFLOW__API__AUTH_BACKEND: xx
    AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_HOST: xx
    AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_PORT: 587
    AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_USER: xx
    AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_PASSWORD: xx
    AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_MAIL_FROM: xx

    _PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS: ${_PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS:- scikit-learn}
  volumes:
    - ./dags:/opt/airflow/dags
    - ./logs:/opt/airflow/logs
    - ./plugins:/opt/airflow/plugins
    - type: bind
      source: ./clean_data
      target: /app/clean_data
    - type: bind
      source: ./raw_files
      target: /app/raw_files
  user: "${AIRFLOW_UID:-50000}:${AIRFLOW_GID:-50000}"
  depends_on:
    redis:
      condition: service_healthy
    postgres:
      condition: service_healthy

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:13
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: airflow
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: airflow
      POSTGRES_DB: airflow
    volumes:
      - postgres-db-volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "pg_isready", "-U", "airflow"]
      interval: 5s
      retries: 5
    restart: always

  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "redis-cli", "ping"]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 30s
      retries: 50
    restart: always

  airflow-webserver:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: webserver
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "--fail", "http://localhost:8080/health"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always

  airflow-scheduler:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: scheduler
    healthcheck:
      test:
        [
          "CMD-SHELL",
          'airflow jobs check --job-type SchedulerJob --hostname "$${HOSTNAME}"',
        ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always

  airflow-worker:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: celery worker
    healthcheck:
      test:
        - "CMD-SHELL"
        - 'celery --app airflow.executors.celery_executor.app inspect ping -d "celery@$${HOSTNAME}"'
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always

  airflow-init:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: version
    environment:
      <<: *airflow-common-env
      _AIRFLOW_DB_UPGRADE: "true"
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_CREATE: "true"
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME: ${_AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME:-airflow}
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD: ${_AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD:-airflow}

  flower:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: celery flower
    ports:
      - 5555:5555
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "--fail", "http://localhost:5555/"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always
  dashboard:
    image: xx
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./clean_data
        target: /app/clean_data
      - type: bind
        source: ./raw_files
        target: /app/raw_files
    ports:
      - 8050:8050

volumes:
  postgres-db-volume:


Thank you
